# How do I add a button to each cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a program which will add the title/artist/album to each cell in a uitableview, but how do I add a button? Every time a song changes the new title/artist/album will be put in a new cell. Every time and new tag is put into a new cell I need a button to be added too. How would I do that? Down below is my code with what I currently have to add a button, but nothing works.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

playButton = UIButton()
let image = "playbutton.png"
playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:image), forState: .Normal)
playButton.addTarget(self, action: "play:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func getNowPlayingItem() {
if let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
    let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
    let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String
    let album = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] as? String
    println("Song: \(title)")
    println("Artist: \(artist)")
    println("Album: \(album)")
    println("\n")


    self.add = [Play(name: "\(title!)\n\(artist!)\n\(album!)")]
    self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

}


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return self.add.count
//return count of objects in array
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell: UITableViewCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
var play: Play

play = add[indexPath.row]

cell.textLabel?.text = play.name

cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3;
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping


playButton.tag = indexPath.row


return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UITableViewCell does not provide UIButton. UITableViewCell has several styles. But None of the style provides UIButton. Here is the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle)

Try to write a new class MyUITableViewCell inherited from UITableViewCell。You can add an UIButton in the [MyUITableViewCell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:].

Comment: But would it be possible to keep adding the play buttons to every cell?

Comment: I think You need to use Sub class of UITableViewCell where you can add a button and provide it tag and get the selected item in tableview.